# ExtJS: Ensure that user submit the form

Tags: javascript, extjs, form-submit

I got several form when user can make various calculation. Forms provide results after user fills in input fields, when most of them or all are filled in onChange event will calculate and display result.

Results need to be saved by submiting the form. Some of user are happy to see result and do not proceed with submit / save operation by closing browser or leaving the page.

How I can catch those action and enforce them to save operation in ExtJS ?

Comment: onbeforeunload is the window's event. are there any onbeforeunload event for Ext.FormPanel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set up an event listener on the `onbeforeunload` event, testing to see if the user submitted the form or not. Check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload